# How can I troubleshoot the 'No available gateway error' in Power BI?

Tags: rest, powerbi

I am having a trouble with Power BI dataset refresh via REST API.

I get this error whenever I try to execute the dataset refresh API:

Last refresh failed: ...
There is no available gateway.

I'm testing on two accounts, and this happens only on one of them.

What is more confusing is that the storage I'm using is cloud based (Azure Data lake). So it doesn't need a gateway connection. And when I refresh the datasets manually it works.

When I get the refresh history for further investigationI get this:

serviceExceptionJson={"errorCode":"DMTS_MonikerWithUnboundDataSources"}

I could use any given help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround solution, although I'm not very convinced this is the source of the problem (maybe the why is still very blurry to me)

First for more context, this is what I'm doing (using the APIs) :

1-Upload a dataset to workspace (import a pbix and skipping report, I only need the parameters and power query within it)

2- Update the parameters

3- Refresh dataset

The thing is, I have a parameter for the url of the datalake data. There are two values of the url, depending on the use case/user.

So what I did, is that I removed that parameter and made two different pbix, each one with its specific url. So then, I import a pbix depending on the use case.

I still don't understand why I get a gateway error, while I should get "error while processing data" message (seeing that it seems to be a data access issue).